# Histograms display issue with pyplot (patches objects?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a time series dataframe.
When i create a histogram as follows:

```
series.hist()
pyplot.show()
```

[image: This is the result (which is desired)]

However when i use this approach:

```
pyplot.hist(series)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: I get this (which is not desired)]

What could be the issue here? The second method takes a very long time to load. Might this be because i've made some changes to the defaults of matplotlib?

This is what is printed when i use the second method without  pyplot.show():

<a list of 731 Lists of Patches objects>)

Could it be the patches objects causing the problem?

Hope this is clear

Comment: You are probably running an old version of matplotlib. Try to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: You are not making an histogram of a time series, you pass `pyplot.hist`a complete dataframe… `pyplot.hist` is forced to unreliably improvise.

Answer (score 1):

I realised the issue was that what i thought was a series was actually a dataframe. Converting using .squeeze() solved the issue!